# New battery is degrading fast?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

So as mentioned in my last post I got a new battery. It is not even a week and Coconut Battery tells this design capacity, around 79%. Is it normal or there is some issue in the battery? I run the following command and it returns the below:

```
ioreg -brc AppleSmartBattery
+-o AppleSmartBattery  <class AppleSmartBattery, id 0x100000261, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 6>
    {
      "TimeRemaining" = 49
      "ExternalConnected" = Yes
      "AvgTimeToEmpty" = 65535
      "AppleRawCurrentCapacity" = 4787
      "InstantTimeToEmpty" = 65535
      "AppleRawMaxCapacity" = 5189
      "ExternalChargeCapable" = Yes
      "FullPathUpdated" = 1692883032
      "CellVoltage" = (4196,4179,4194,0)
      "Voltage" = 12575
      "BatteryInvalidWakeSeconds" = 30
      "AdapterInfo" = 0
      "MaxCapacity" = 5189
      "PermanentFailureStatus" = 0
      "DesignCycleCount70" = 65535
      "Manufacturer" = "SMP"
      "AppleRawAdapterDetails" = ({"Source"=1,"AdapterID"=2337,"SerialNumber"=19703559,"FamilyCode"=133,"Watts"=60,"Current"=3650,"Voltage"=16500})
      "Location" = 0
      "CurrentCapacity" = 4787
      "LegacyBatteryInfo" = {"Amperage"=743,"Flags"=7,"Capacity"=5189,"Current"=4787,"Voltage"=12575,"Cycle Count"=8}
      "BatteryFCCData" = {}
      "BatteryInstalled" = Yes
      "FirmwareSerialNumber" = 1
      "CycleCount" = 8
      "PackReserve" = 200
      "DesignCapacity" = 6600
      "OperationStatus" = 33795
      "ManufactureDate" = 22113
      "AvgTimeToFull" = 49
      "ChargerData" = {"ChargingVoltage"=12576,"ChargingCurrent"=1280,"NotChargingReason"=0}
      "BatterySerialNumber" = "D864453S2TBFVN7AG"
      "BootPathUpdated" = 1692813365
      "BatteryData" = {"StateOfCharge"=93,"PMUConfigured"=640,"Voltage"=12574,"QmaxCell1"=6097,"SystemPower"=2474,"QmaxCell2"=6088,"QmaxCell0"=6105,"CycleCount"=8,"DesignCapacity"=$
      "PostDischargeWaitSeconds" = 120
      "Temperature" = 3057
      "UserVisiblePathUpdated" = 1692883332
      "IOReportLegendPublic" = Yes
      "InstantAmperage" = 735
      "FullyCharged" = No
      "ManufacturerData" = <000000000702000a03890000034a34340330304103534449034800>
      "DeviceName" = "bq20z451"
      "MaxErr" = 1
      "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
      "IOReportLegend" = ({"IOReportChannels"=((7167869599145487988,6460407809,"BatteryCycleCount")),"IOReportGroupName"="Battery","IOReportChannelInfo"={"IOReportChannelUnit"=0}})
      "Amperage" = 743
      "IsCharging" = Yes
      "DesignCycleCount9C" = 1000
      "PostChargeWaitSeconds" = 120
      "AdapterDetails" = {"Source"=1,"AdapterID"=2337,"SerialNumber"=19703559,"FamilyCode"=133,"Watts"=60,"Current"=3650,"Voltage"=16500}
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Contact the vendor who supplied this battery and request a replacement, or at least an explanation. Unfortunately, unscrupulous vendors will sell "as new" batteries pulled from used systems.

Comment: It’s a defective battery.  It could be NOS (New, Old Stock) where it sat around for years degrading or just a poor quality build.  Either way, you need to return it.

Comment: @Allan what should I say to him when returning? and what should I check while having another?

Comment: Let your supplier know that it failed out of the box and won’t hold a charge. That’s the truth. As for what to look for, in one of the linked dupes I reference some things to look for (like an 18 month or better warranty). However, the first thing you should check for is a manufacturing date. Anything over a year old should be skipped.

Comment: @Allan as per the sshot, it says it was manufactured on 1st march.

Comment: That’s data written to the battery controller.  Look for a date code imprinted on the battery itself.  But, keep in mind, these are devices that rely on a *chemical* reaction to produce electrons.  You could easily get a defective battery manufactured just yesterday as well.

Comment: @Allan in short it's all about luck.

Comment: Buy from Ali Expess < luck.  Buy genuine Apple or batteries made from LG/Panasonic cells > Luck.  “Luck” plays a part, but much less so from reputable manufacturers/vendors.   Even Apple will ship out a faulty battery in a new Mac from time to time.